# Get filepath relative to Apache's document root

Tags: php

Given `$abs_path='/var/www/foo/html/bar/bla/bla';`, how do I get the path relative to Apache's document root?

I recognize I could just use somethinglike `$rel_path=str_replace ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$abs_path,1 );`, but curious if there is a built in function.

Comment: I know PHP has a function to convert relative paths to absolute ([`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)), but I don't think it has one for the other way around.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I looked at realpath first, and they didn't have any "See Alsos" so expect you are right.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the "built in way" to do it. But why would you even want that?

Comment: @dan-klasson  Image is uploaded to the server and saved with a random name.  I wish to return to the client the relative URL of the file.

Comment: So set the upload path in a config file, use environment variables or whatever your framework recommends. Then use that instead.